# How to stop my text messages from appearing on iPad

Tags: sharing

My son is under 13 and shares my Apple ID I would like to stop my texts from appearing on his iPad does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 5):

Create an independent [Apple ID](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201084) for him; as a minor he will have to be added m to your family group with [Family Sharing](http://www.apple.com/ios/whats-new/family-sharing/), which will allow him to access most of what you have paid for and ask for permission to buy apps / media.
Apple IDs were never meant to be shared.

Changing an Apple ID has some implications of course:

- If you change it in the Game Center, progress associated to the old Apple ID will be lost on some games.
- Apps bought or downloaded with the old Apple ID will keep asking for its password to update. If you download them again with the new ID most should work under Family Sharing (i.e., you don't have to pay again; it's a per app setting defined by the developer)

Comment: Definitely, Family Sharing in iOS 8 makes this even more apparent.

Comment: The OP should still consider using Parental Controls. I have highlighted how he can do that using Restrictions within General Settings.

Comment: If I create a new Apple ID for him on his ipad will he still have all his games and apps just as they were?

Comment: @user141673 I'll update the answer to address your concern

Answer (score 1):

You can either disable iMessage on the iPad using **Settings>Messages>iMessage** and slide the switch to the left. This will remove all of your text data and the link from iMessage to your iPad.

If you just do not want the notifications to show up but you still be able to use Messages for yourself first go to **Settings>Notifications>Allow Notifications** and switch that off.

Next go to **Settings>General>Restrictions** and enable restrictions. It will ask you to enter an alternate pin. You can then go to messages, and any other apps that you do not want him using for that matter and switch them off so that he can not open them. Then when you want to use them again, enter your alternate pin and switch them back on for your personal use.